# Manual pagination:- next button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, schema

On Button click event I execute a new query i get a new table but i am unable to populate it on to the same grid view. Is there any why where i can use schema instead of dataTables.

```
private void GetData()//This method Displays the Datatable onto the Grid
{            
    int intCount = 0;
    int.TryParse(txt_messagecount.Text, out intCount);
    DataTable dtData = null;
    //dtData = _objIMRSData.GetData(txt_fromdate.Text, txt_todata.Text, txt_messagecount.Text);
    dtData = _objIMRSData.GetTransactionData( txt_fromdate.Text, txt_todata.Text,intCount );           
    grd_transactionLog.DataSource = dtData;
    grd_transactionLog.DataBind();
    dtData.Clear();        
}

//On Button click event I execute a new query i get a new table 
//but i am unable to   populate it on to the same grid view
protected void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs  e)
{ 
    int messageCount = int.Parse(txt_messagecount.Text);
    string lastRecord = grd_transactionLog.Rows[messageCount-1].Cells[1].Text;
    DataTable dtData1 = null;
    //dtData = _objIMRSData.GetData(lastRecord, txt_todata.Text, txt_messagecount.Text);
    dtData1 = _objIMRSData.GetTransactionData(lastRecord, txt_todata.Text, messageCount);
    //grd_transactionLog.Columns.Clear();            
    grd_transactionLog.DataSource = dtData1;
    grd_transactionLog.DataBind();
    dtData1.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Does `GetData()` get called on Page Load?

Comment: Side-Note: `DataTable.Clear` is a relatively expensive method and you're using it without a reason.

Comment: Not only do you not need to do `DataTable.Clear()`, you also don't need to set `dtData1` to null.

Answer (score 0):

Reassign the `datasource`. In the `click` event do this.

```
grd_transactionLog.DataSource = null;
grd_transactionLog.DataSource = dtData1;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but the solution is right for the question i wrote i was sending the wrong query so it is popping the same datatable back